# Need to filter Super Search results by relationship in custom field

Tags: stash, multi-site-manager, relationships, supersearch

We have an EE site for a hospital with two sites, default_site and another_site

Default_site has almost all the unique content, such as:

- Physicians

  - Can have multiple specialties
  - Custom_field (checkbox) to display on Another_site
- Specialties

Another_site pretty much just has custom page content.

We are using Super Search to search both Physicians and Specialties from Default_site and pages from Another_site

The problem is, we only want to show specialties in the search results IF the physicians have the custom field checked to display on Another_site

We can filter the physicians pretty easily, but are having a hard time figuring out how to only show only the specialties in the search results whose physicians have the checkbox checked.

Any thoughts? Ideas?